# Problem with leading zero's in a vector array of doubles

Tags: stl, vector, c++

I'm tring to calculate the standard deviation of a vector of doubles (called A). 
Now I have a function called StDev that will do this. However, the first 
few elements of vector A are zero and I need to remove these. To do this I 
create a sub-array and then pass this to my StDev function as follows:

```
 std::vector<double> Array(find_if(Data.begin(), Data.end(), std::bind1st (std::not_equal_to<double>(), 0.0)), Data.end());     

 double standard_deviation = StDev(Array);
```

Is there a way of doing this without having to create the vector 'Array' which 
is only used once. Can I somehow pass the required sub-array directly?

Thanks!

Comment: If you wrote your standard deviation function to take two iterators, defining a range, that would allow you to avoid the copy altogether, wouldn't it?

Comment: If the zeros are not valid data, why are they in the vector to begin with?  If they are valid, why would you not want to StdDev to account for them?

Comment: @John Dibling: At some point I hope to re-write the code so that the vector contains only relevant data but for now I'm just looking for some simple fix: James's answer below is what I'll probably use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can modify your `StDev` function to take an iterator range instead of a whole container, you can do this quite easily:

```
template <typename ForwardIt>
std::iterator_traits<ForwardIt>::value_type 
StDev(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last) { /* ... */ }

// called as:
double stdev = StDev(Data.begin(), Data.end());

// or:
double stdev = StDev(
    find_if(Data.begin(), Data.end(), 
            std::bind1st(std::not_equal_to<double>(), 0.0)), 
    Data.end());
```

Comment: Nice and instructive answer !

Comment: Ideally I'd like to avoid re-writting my StDev function.

Comment: @Wawel100: "Can I somehow pass the required sub-array directly?" => Yes, use what James McNellis suggested. This is by far the most flexible and efficient solution.

Comment: @Wawel100:  This doesn't really require a whole lot of changes:  you just have to use `first` and `last` instead of `c.begin()` and `c.end()` inside of the new `StDev()` function.  You can keep your existing `StDev()` function and create a new `StDevRange()` function template if you'd prefer (`StDev()` could then be implemented in terms of `StDevRange()`.  This would keep you from having to change all the places that call `StDev()`, but really, that probably isn't too large a task).

Comment: I've implemented your solution as an alternative I guess I could also pass a tempory object (?):    double standard_deviation = StDev(std::vector<double>(find_if (Data.begin(), Data.end(), std::bind1st (std::not_equal_to<double>(), 0.0)), Data.end()));

Answer (score 1):

You could change your `StDev` function so that it skips however many elements at the start of the array that are zero.